# How to get all array items in values from dictionary Python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to save all keys and values from a dictionary to txt file as:

```
f=open("output.txt","w") 
for keys,values in pred_x.items(): 
    s=str(keys)+" "+str(values)+"\n" 
    b=f.write(s) 
f.close()
```

However, size of array in values is >3000 and the output is:

```
dict_values([array(['Q1', 'Q5', 'Q9', ..., 'Q3001', 'Q3012', 'Q3015'], dtype='<U5'), array([[11319,  3884,  9555, ..., 14079,     0,     0]
```

How can I obtain full size of array in values without "..."?

**Update:**
I tried with csv file as:

```
with open("dict.csv", "w") as csv_file: 
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in test_x.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])
```

And the csv output still shows not enough items in array:
[image]

Comment: Don't use `str`. Why are you trying to save this to a .txt file? What is your purpose? Why not some other sort of well-established serialization format, like JSON, or even pickle?

Comment: why dont you save it as json?

Comment: Make it a pickle or a csv file

Comment: I tried with csv file as: with open("dict.csv", "w") as csv_file: 
                                           writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                                           for key, value in test_x.items():
                                                    writer.writerow([key, value])      
But the csv file shows: key1 ['Q1' 'Q5' 'Q9' ... 'Q3001' 'Q3012' 'Q3015']

Comment: With your updated edit, is there anything that is happening but should not? Do you have any further question?

Comment: It still happens in with csv file.

Comment: What is the type of `pred_x` and `test_x`? It would be helpful if you added code that showed us how you could create similar objects (but of a smaller size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below

The idea is to convert the np array to python list

```
import csv

import numpy as np

test_x = {'key1': np.array([1, 2, 3])}

with open("dict.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in test_x.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value.tolist()])
```